# Heroku installation error

Tags: node.js, macos, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I have been trying to make heroku work on my mac. I have installed Heroku-Toolbelt already. But when I run "heroku login" on zsh console, I get this error:

```
$ heroku login
heroku-cli: Installing core plugins...
 ▸    npm ERR! Darwin 15.3.0
 ▸    npm ERR! argv "/Users/Deepen/.heroku/node-v5.4.1-darwin-x64/bin/node"  
"/Users/Deepen/.heroku/node-v5.4.1-darwin-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/cli.js"   
"remove" "heroku-apps" "heroku-cli-addons" "heroku-fork" "heroku-git" 
"heroku-local" "heroku-run" "heroku-spaces" "heroku-status"
 ▸    npm ERR! node v5.4.1
 ▸    npm ERR! npm  v3.3.10
 ▸    npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
 ▸
 ▸    npm ERR! Cannot find module 'npm-autoinit/autoinit'
 ▸    npm ERR!
 ▸    npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
 ▸    npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
 ▸    npm WARN ENOENT ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Deepen/.heroku/package.json'
 ▸    npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON .heroku No description
 ▸    npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON .heroku No repository field.
 ▸    npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON .heroku No README data
 ▸    npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON .heroku No license field.
 ▸    npm ERR! Darwin 15.3.0
 ▸    npm ERR! argv "/Users/Deepen/.heroku/node-v5.4.1-darwin-x64/bin/node"   "/Users/Deepen/.heroku/node-v5.4.1-darwin-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/cli.js" "remove" "heroku-apps" "heroku-cli-addons" "heroku-fork" "heroku-git" "heroku-local" "heroku-run" "heroku-spaces" "heroku-status"
 ▸    npm ERR! node v5.4.1
 ▸    npm ERR! npm  v3.3.10
 ▸
 ▸    npm ERR! Callback called more than once.
 ▸    npm ERR!
 ▸    npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
  ▸    npm ERR!     
 ▸
 ▸    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
 ▸    npm ERR!     /Users/Deepen/.heroku/npm-debug.log
▸    exit status 1
heroku-cli: Installing core plugins (retrying)...
```

Comment: Do you have any references to `npm-autoinit/autoinit` in your [npmrc](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc)?

Comment: @RansomBriggs Yes, I do. But the problem persists!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just shipped a fix for this, could you please `heroku update` and try again?

Comment: @Deepen could you please remove `~/.heroku` and run `heroku update` again?  That should clear out any old installation files you have and install the latest version (`4.27.21-839acbb`)

Comment: @Deepen how are you using `npm-autoinit/autoinit` I had assumed it was part of an `onload-script`, please let me know if you are using it in a different way.

Comment: @Ransom Briggs, please see my question below

Comment: I had a similar problem, with a somewhat different error message (could not find packages.json in /home/lonnon/.heroku), but it was solved through similar means. I removed the toolbelt with `sudo apt-get --purge remove heroku_toolbelt`, then removed the `~/.heroku` directory.

After reinstalling from the original install-ubuntu.sh script, I ran `heroku` on the command line. heroku-cli failed again at the "Installing core plugins" step, but after running it again (and a long wait at the core plugins step) it finally worked.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did to fix it.

I checked where node 5.9.1 was installed on my system (Mac El Capitan):

```
  % which node
  ~/.nvm/versions/node/v5.9.1
```

Then I copied the whole thing under ~/.heroku and changed the name of the directory:

```
cp -r ~/.nvm/versions/node/v5.9.1 ~/.heroku
mv ~/.heroku/v5.9.1 ~/.heroku/node-v5.9.1-darwin-x64
```

That did the trick for me and hopefully it will help someone else too since it took me a long time to figure it out.